# Как в модуле win_command или win_package для ansible задать корректные коды завершения?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, ansible, yaml

Пытаюсь поставить `AutoCAD` на машину с помощью `Ansible`. Технически всё ставится и работает, но меня выбешивает, что:

1. При установке через модуль `win_package` ругается на неверный `product_id`, хотя я его вытаскивал после ручной установки через `wmi`.
2. При установке через `win_command` ругается на `"rc": 1641`, а при повтороном запуске уже возвращает `"rc": 0` и всё хорошо.

Что я хочу:

1. При использовании `win_package` или не указывать `product_id` вообще или указывать любой, но чтобы ошибка не доставала (только по продукт ид. Остальные - пусть).
2. При использовании `win_command` заранее сказать ансиблу, что и код `0` и `1641` - хорошие и не надо писать фейлиды и алярмы.

Что я уже попробовал:

1. В `win_package` `expected_return_code: [0,1641]` не работает. Вернее его перекрывает ошибка про продуктид.
2. В `win_command` `failed_when: rc != 0 or rc != 1641` тоже не отрабатывает скорее всего из-за синтаксиса. Перепробовал разные варианты написания - всё равно не работает. Подсмотрел [тут](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands).

```
ubuntu 16.04, windows 7 pro

ansible 2.3.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65747/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-don-rumata).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение `rc != 0 or rc != 1641` всегда истинно; я думаю вы хотели использовать `and`, а не `or` или общее отрицание.

Плюс, нужно использовать зарегистрированное значение, у которого уже проверять свойство `rc`:

```
- win_command: mycommand
  register: cmd_res
  failed_when: not (cmd_res.rc == 0 or cmd_res.rc == 1641)
```

Comment: А откуда взялось `cmd_res`? Это какая-то зарезервированная переменная? Я не до конца понимаю что пользователь пишет сам, а что зашито в коде.

Comment: `cmd_res` – зарегистрированная переменная, в которую запишется результат выполнения таски. Для сохранения результата в переменные используется конструкция `register: <var_name>`.

Comment: А, т.е. не имеет значения что именно я напишу после `register`? Любой стринг без пробелов будет восприниматься как имя переменной?

Comment: Любое допустимое имя для переменной. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables